# Как отследить переход на новую страницу используя API Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как отследить переход на новую страницу (не на вкладку) используя API Chrome?

Пытаюсь так, но, наверное, неправильно:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(win){
    chrome.windows.get(win.id,{populate:true},function(tabwin){
        setTimeout(function(){
            //chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabwin.tabs[0].id,{code:"alert(JSON.stringify(window));",runAt:'document_idle'});
            console.log('onCreated');
        },500);
    });
});
```

**Дополнение:**

---

Вылетает ошибка, когда пытаемся отправить сообщения:
extensions::schemaUtils:113 Uncaught Error: Invocation of form tabs.sendMessage(integer) doesn't match definition tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, optional object options, optional function responseCallback)

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    if(changeInfo.url != null) {

        console.log('изменилось '+changeInfo.url);
        console.log('tabId '+tabId);
        setTemer(tabId);
    }
});


 function setTemer(tabs_id){
    setInterval(function(){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs_id), {greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {

            //console.log("ID - "+tabs);
        };
    }, 6000);
 }
```

Comment: как минимум попробуйте скобку убрать chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs_id), {greeting: "hello"}, ....

Comment: @UserName   Просто я хочу отправить сообщения. Если  уберу `sendMessage` то даже и не знаю как я смогу его отпарвить, каким образом.

Comment: обновил ответ. Код проверил

Comment: Забыл уточнить. Код в который я дописал в ответе рабочий при условии что у вас приемник в content_scripts написан без ошибок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, воспользоватся событием `chrome.tabs.api*` `onUpdated`.

Срабатывает когда обновляется вкладка. Переход по ссылкам якорям тоже отлавливаются.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    if(changeInfo.url != null) {

        alert(changeInfo.url);
    }
});
```

`tabId` - Как видно из названия это id вкладки в которой сработало событие.

`changeInfo` - объект содержащий изменения обновляемой вкладки.

- url - Свойство объекта `changeInfo`. Содержит значение если `url` изменился.

`tab` - Сама вкладка, в которой сработало событие.

[tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) | [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)

**UPD**

```
 function setTemer(tabs_id){
    setInterval(function(){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs_id), {greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {

            //console.log("ID - "+tabs);
        };
    }, 6000);
 }
```

Не заработает хотя бы потому что у вас лишняя скобка сразу после `tabs_id`.

И отсутствует скобка после закрывающей фигурной скобки callback'a.

Из-за этого вы и получаете ошибку представленную в дополнении.

```
function setTemer(tabs_id) {

    setInterval(function () {

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs_id, {greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {

            //console.log("ID - "+tabs);
        });
    }, 6000);
}
```

Остальную часть кода не трогал. Отработало нормально. Из `background` скрипта сообщения дошли до `content_scripts`.

Comment: Спасибо. А как id выставить для каждой вкладке? Расширение должно работать и с теми вкладками на которых я сейчас не нахожусь.

Comment: @gilo1212, что значит выставить id для каждой вкладки? Когда сработает событие, вы и так получаете tabId обновляемой владки. В примере выше в callbaсk'е первый параметр.
Оно сработает на всех вкладках, даже если они не активны. Т.е например из активной вкладки кликаем по ссылкам и открываем их в отдельных вкладках, на каждую из новых вкладок событие отработает.

Comment: Спасибо, но похоже это не совсем то что я ищу. Мне нужно с событием перехода на новую вкладку, получать ту информацию которую мы отправили с popup menu. Если Вас не затруднит, обратите пожалуйста внимание на этот вопрос : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-popup-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-js-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB

Comment: Кстати почемуто код не работает, я его добавил в background.js

Comment: @gilo1212, код должен работать. Я его копировал из редактора, т.е проверял. Проверьте в `manifest.json` секцию `permission`. Должно быть выставленно разрешение на работу с вкладками - `tabs`."

На счет вашего второго вопроса. Вы хотели отследить смену фокуса с popup'a и продолжать через интервалы слать сообщения? Т.е этот вопрос продолжение того, так?

Comment: @ `Кстати почемуто код не работает, я его добавил в background.js Я обновляю страницу через content.js `setInterval(function(){location.href = 'http://regular-viragenia/index-js.html';}, 6000);`      может из-за этого не работает.  А вот разрешения.   ` "permissions": ["tabs","webRequest","webNavigation","management","activeTab", "http://*/*","https://*/*"]``

Comment: Да, всё верно,  тот вопрос продолжение этого. На самом деле что нужно: Я открываю popupmenu расширешния, в нём я выбрал radio button, нажал кнопку отправить, сообщение отправилось в background.js, с него в content.js. Это всё работает. Но, когда я обновляю страницу через  `location.href = 'regular-viragenia/index-js.html';` , то я не знаю как мне получить ту информацию которую я отправлял с popupmenu, самого расширения. Возможно ли как-то её получить? Вкладок в браузере будет открыто около 15.

Comment: Кстати, `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` заработал.

Comment: @gilo1212, день какой-то не мой. Я опять не до конца понял. Отвечу в том вопросе, а вы меня поправите если что

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос новыми данными. Теперь проблема не могу отправить сообщение по tab_id, хотя tab_id я получаю. Очень тсранно.

Comment: Большое спасибо. По-моему, всё начало работать как нужно)