# Как сделать что бы при закрытом popup самого расрирения, js работал?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Как сделать что бы при закрытом popup самого расрирения, js работал ?

У меня есть расширение для GoogleChrome. Когда я открываю его popup menu, то этот код отправляет сообщения в background, а background, отправляет его в вкладку в которую внедряется js код, и мы получаем сообщения. Но, когда я **закрываю** **popup menu**, setInterval перестаёт работать. Как сделать так, чтобы он продолжал свою работу даже при свернутом popup menu?

```
setInterval(function(){
  chrome.extension.sendMessage("тест 777");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ставить `setInterval` в `background`.
Например, если нужно делать задержку при действии, то сначала отправляем в `background`, а там уже ставим `setInterval` для отправки на вкладку.

Comment: а как-же id вкладки узнать? Я делаю так, но это не правильно7 ` chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
     chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: message }, function (response) {
         });
     });

 });`   вот это id означает, что будет отправлять в ту вкладку в которой мы сейчас находимся - `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: message }, func`

Comment: @gilo1212, что бы сохранять id, можно создать функцию в которую будет передаваться id в виде аргумента, тогда при вызове функции `setInterval` id будет сохраняться, только не передавайте объект, он передаётся ввиде ссылки на него, а не сама переменная.